# Conditonally create temporary table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Invoking the following SQL leads to a warning 'column "s" has type "unknown"' which I can understand. What I'm trying to accomplish is to conditionally create a temporary in preparation of running a SELECT over multiple schemas. Can I approach this in another way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_exists(v_table text)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    v_count int;
    v_sql text;
BEGIN
  v_sql = 
    'SELECT ' ||
    '  count(1) ' ||
    'FROM ' ||
    '  information_schema.tables ' ||
    'WHERE ' ||
    E'  table_name=\'' || v_table || E'\'';

  EXECUTE v_sql INTO v_count;
  RETURN v_count>0;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;

DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT distinct table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'public') AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
  IF table_exists('combined_settings') THEN
    EXECUTE '
    INSERT INTO combined_settings
      SELECT '''|| r.table_schema ||''' AS s, prefix, id, value FROM '|| quote_ident(r.table_schema) ||'.settings WHERE id=''VERSION''  
    ';

  ELSE
    EXECUTE '
    CREATE TEMP TABLE combined_settings AS
      SELECT '''|| r.table_schema ||''' AS s, prefix, id, value FROM '|| quote_ident(r.table_schema) ||'.settings WHERE id=''VERSION''
    ';
  END IF;

  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE '
  COPY (SELECT * FROM combined_settings) TO ''/tmp/out-' || current_database() || ''' CSV;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS combined_settings;
  ';
END$$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a function to check if the temporary table exists. You do not even need the table. The query below gives all tables *settings* in all schemas (except of *public* and system schemas) in a database, with appropriate schema names:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND table_name = 'settings'
    AND table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'public')
```

In the anonymous function below we shall build sql query instead of storing results in a temp table, according to the following pseudocode:

```
for all tables 'settings':
    build select query text and store it in 'vselect',
    append 'vselect' to 'vquery' joining consecutive selects with word 'UNION'
```

At the end of the loop we shall have in *vquery* something like this:

```
SELECT 'schema1', prefix, id, value FROM schema1.settings WHERE id = 'VERSION'
UNION
SELECT 'schema2', prefix, id, value FROM schema2.settings WHERE id = 'VERSION'
-- etc
```

and we are going to use this in COPY to a file.

The function:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    vrec record;
    vquery text = '';
    vselect text;
BEGIN
    FOR vrec IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE 
            table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
            AND table_name = 'settings'
            AND table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'public')
    LOOP
        vselect = format(
            'SELECT ''%s'', prefix, id, value FROM %s.%s WHERE id = ''VERSION''',
            vrec.table_schema, quote_ident(vrec.table_schema), vrec.table_name);
        IF vquery = '' THEN vquery = vselect;
        ELSE vquery = format('%s UNION %s', vquery, vselect);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE format('COPY (%s) TO ''/tmp/out-%s'' CSV', vquery, current_database());
END $$;
```